# .htaccess rewrite url with page name slash GET parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, url-rewriting, get

I'm trying to rewrite my URL from `request/2` to `request?number=2`

I tried to write this in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^request/(.*)$ request?number=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But the result is a `404 Error`

Can someone help me?

Comment: try: `RewriteRule ^request/([\w-]+)/?$ request.php?number=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: It works, thanks! Is there any way to avoid writing the extension instead? @anubhava

Comment: Why avoid? extension is not being shown in URL, it is only being used in a rule

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##To remove .php extension eg--> someone hits http://localhost:80/test.php it will redirect to http://localhost:80/test  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]*)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301]
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

##All non-existing files/directories will come in this rule whose URI starts from request. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^request/([\w-]+)/?$ request.php?number=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

##All non-existing files/directories will come in this rule set apart from URI which starts from request which is taken care above.   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: There is some error, it returns me an error 500

Comment: @IvanCisternino, ok, could you please do let me know url which you are hitting(a sample url will help here).

Comment: The error is in the removal of the extension, in the first 5 lines @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Now there is no more error, but redirect to page without extension does not work @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @IvanCisternino, ok could you please post a sample link for same here will take a look

Comment: @IvanCisternino, Rules are working fine for my localhost, could you please do make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs once?

Comment: If I try to type `localhost/mypage.php` it returns a `Moved Permanently`

Comment: @IvanCisternino That seems to be a browser cache issue. Try using a different browser to test the URL

Comment: Even changing browsers the situation remains the same

Comment: @IvanCisternino, these rules had worked for me, any errors you are seeing after hitting your url in logs?